# Как скрыть верхушку виджета?

Tags: c++, qt

Тобишь нужно скрыть верхушку у самописного диалогового окна (там где заголовок, кнопка выхода). При этом такая конструкция при инициализации не помогает:

```
: ::QDialog{parent, Qt::WindowTitleHint | Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint},
```

система линукс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По вкусу:

```
// Убрать рамку
QDialog (parent, Qt::FramelessWindowHint)
```

или

```
// Выключить, включённый по умолчанию Qt::WindowTitleHint
QDialog (parent, Qt::CustomizeWindowHint)
```

См. [Значения флагов](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum) и пример [Windndow Flags](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-windowflags-example.html).

ЗЫ: «Верхушка окна» в простонародии называется «Title bar» aka «Заголовок окна»